# how to use more than 2 functions in -InitializationScript in start-job

Tags: start-job

I want to use 2 functions in -InitializationScript in the following PowerShell start-job code:

```
$IISfunc={ Function pool_RemoteServer ($PoolName,$server)
{
    "doing something in iis"
} 
}

$AppState= { Function GetAppState($AppServer,$AppName)
           {
            "doing something in appserver"

            }
            }

$block ={
        Param([string] $AppServer,
              [string] $AppName,
              [string] $PoolName,
              [string] $AppState,
              [string] $IISfunc
             )
              pool_RemoteServer -PoolName $PoolName -server $AppServer
              GetAppState -AppServer $AppServer -AppName $AppName
               }


Get-Job | Remove-Job
$MaxThreads = 20
invoke-service -JobserviceName  $JobserviceName

    foreach ($AppServer in $AppServers -split ",")
            {
                While ($(Get-Job -state running).count -ge $MaxThreads){
                    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 3
            }
        Start-Job -Scriptblock $block -ArgumentList $AppServer,$AppName,$PoolName -InitializationScript $AppState,$IISfunc

            }

While ($(Get-Job -State Running).count -gt 0){
    start-sleep 1
}

foreach($job in Get-Job){
    $info= Receive-Job -Id ($job.Id)
}

Get-Job | Remove-Job
```

I had encountered this error:
Start-Job : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' required by parameter 'InitializationScript'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:21 char:95
+ ... lizationScript $AppState,$IISfunc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! Its so simple problem! Please include the following solution in your code:

```
  $func={ Function pool_RemoteServer ($PoolName,$server)
        {
            "doing something in iis"
        } 

          Function GetAppState($AppServer,$AppName)
        {
        "doing something in appserver"
        }
        }
```

- Kind regards